# Rails 3, mongoid, carrierwave, nested object form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave to upload photos to a World model. I can't seem to get the upload form right:

```
class World
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document

  mount_uploader :image, WorldPhotoUploader

  embedded_in :world
end


# show.haml
= form_for world, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  = f.fields_for world.photos.build do |photo|
    = photo.file_field :image
```

This gives me this form input:

```
<input id="world_photo_image" name="world[photo][image]" type="file">
```

Which doesn't work, I get

```
Cannot serialize an object of class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into BSON.

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"e2PzZlSY0NwiCqDWn7ZMNwqnypP+GC23PcMuy+uGyF0=",
 "world"=>{"photo"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000103182ac8 @original_filename="Black Box fish.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"world[photo][image]\"; filename=\"Black Box fish.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/IY/IY7PGAf2F9OD6CIKr1RQo++++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110917-57084-zwoyfy>>}},
 "commit"=>"Upload",
 "id"=>"pluto"}
```

The input that seems to work is:

```
<input id="world_photo_image" name="world[photos][][image]" type="file">
```

But i'm not sure how to create the form to get that

Answer (score 1):

I have this (with your names):

```
 <%= form_for @world, :multipart => true do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for 'photos[0]' do |attachments| %>
     <%= attachments.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

This gives the desired format. You can increase the index with javascript if you don't know beforehand how many images are going to be uploaded.

Then you may simply have in you controller:

```
@world = World.new(params[:world])
```

But don't forget this line in your model:

```
embeds_many :photos, cascade_callbacks: true
```

as per [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues#issue/81) issue.

Also, it is redundant to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for an embedded document as this is the default.

Comment: Adding `cascade_callbacks: true` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

`10.times {@world.photos.build}` in your World controller and you will get 10 input fields with correct names, thanks goes to `Radar @ irc.freenode.net #RubyOnRails`